# How can I get the date of selected week which are in the date range selected

Tags: c#, datetime

how can I get the **date of selected week** which are in the **date range selected** in C#.

I am new in C#, please help me out to save these dates in DB, which comes under the date range

[image]

Comment: so you want the date corresponding to each day selected? 
Basically it will be the date of the beginning of your range, and you add the number of days you need to get to your day.

Comment: @DimitriBosteels Yes

Comment: So for your example you want 10/24, 10/26, 10/28, 10/29, 10/31, 11/2, 11/4, 11/5, 11/7, 11/9, and 11/11?

Comment: First parse the dates into `DateTime` and you can use `DateTime.AddDay` and `DateTime.DayOfWeek` to figure out the rest.

Comment: @juharr yes exactly these dates.

Comment: What you are looking for can be achieved by this
1. Get the dates between from and to. 
2. Match the DateTime's property DayOfWeek along with the checkbox selection value.
3. Complete your logic. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make all the possible Dates between the ranges and then check against a list of DaysOfWeeks:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var selectedDayOfWeeks = new List<DayOfWeek>{DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Saturday};
        var startDate = new DateTime(2017, 10, 24);
        var endDate = new DateTime(2017, 10, 28);

        var possibleDates = new List<DateTime>();
        for(var current = startDate; current <= endDate; current= current.AddDays(1))
        {
            if(selectedDayOfWeeks.Contains(current.DayOfWeek))
            {
                possibleDates.Add(current);
            }
        }

        foreach(var d in possibleDates){
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but how can i get the checked days of the week, in DayOfWeek(model) ? sorry for this silly question but i am new in c#

Answer (score 0):

This is one way...

```
        var from = DateTime.Parse("10/24/2018");
        var to = DateTime.Parse("11/14/2018");
        var dayList = new List<DateTime>();

        for (var day = from.Date; day.Date <= to.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
        {
            if
            (
                day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday ||
                day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday ||
                day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday ||
                day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
            )
            {
                dayList.Add(day);
            }
        }
```

DayOfWeek is an enumeration in the system namespace, you can determine your day of week check box and add a corresponding enum value to a list of DayOfWeek and use as Kevin Smith demonstrated

```
        var selectedDaysOfWeek = new List<DayOfWeek>();
        var from = DateTime.Parse("10/24/2018");
        var to = DateTime.Parse("11/14/2018");
        var dayList = new List<DateTime>();

        if (checkBoxMonday.IsChecked) { selectedDaysOfWeek.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday); }
        if (checkBoxTuesday.IsChecked) { selectedDaysOfWeek.Add(DayOfWeek.Tuesday); }
        if (checkBoxWednesday.IsChecked) { selectedDaysOfWeek.Add(DayOfWeek.Wednesday); }
        if (checkBoxThursday.IsChecked) { selectedDaysOfWeek.Add(DayOfWeek.Thursday); }
        if (checkBoxFriday.IsChecked) { selectedDaysOfWeek.Add(DayOfWeek.Friday); }
        if (checkBoxSaturday.IsChecked) { selectedDaysOfWeek.Add(DayOfWeek.Saturday); }
        if (checkBoxSunday.IsChecked) { selectedDaysOfWeek.Add(DayOfWeek.Sunday); }

        for (var day = from.Date; day.Date <= to.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (selectedDaysOfWeek.Contains(day.DayOfWeek))
            {
                dayList.Add(day);
            }
        }

        foreach(var day in dayList)
        {
            // Add to day to DB
        }
```